Salesforce Objects in PowerBI
I'm trying to build something fairly basic in Power BI (or so I thought!)
I've pulled in four Salesforce tables, joined on standard fields:
Campaign (joined to Campaign Member on CM.Campaign ID to C.ID)
Campaign Member (joined to Lead on CM.LeadID to L.ID)
Lead (joined to user on L.CreatedByID to U.ID)
User

My table visual contains:
CreatedDate from Lead
Name from Lead (renamed Lead Name)
Link to Lead from Lead (custom column, made by concatenating text with Lead ID to make a URL)
Name from User (renamed Created By)
Name from Campaign (renamed Campaign)
I've selected "Show items with no data" in the columns part of build visual, with the intent to see leads created by user without a campaign.
This has given the desired visual, showing all leads, but with blank in the Campaign column where there's no entry in the campaign table.
However, I'm unable to filter on blanks in the Campaign filter.  There's no option in the basic filtering, and choosing "is blank" in the advanced filtering brings back nothing at all, just clears my table.
Also odd, is that turning the Link to Lead column into hyperlinks using conditional formatting only converts them where there's a result in the Campaign column.
I'm wondering if someone could possibly explain to me why that might be happening?  Hopefully the explanation makes sense, it's hard to explain properly without showing but that would breach company policy!
Level of experience on PowerBI = pretty much absolute beginner, but have some SQL knowledge so not all concepts are foreign.
Thanks in advance,
Ryan
I've tried merge queries, I've tried creating custom columns and measures to filter on the blanks, tried using chatGPT to diagnose the issue, nothing has worked so far.  Also tried creating a new measure for the count of Leads without a Campaign in the Campaign Member table to use for filtering within the visual, but that didn't even create a column in the table when I added it in
